# sending file from jsp to spring controller using ajax

Tags: spring-mvc, file-io, facebook-javascript-sdk, fileinputstream

I have an image file that i need to send from my jsp page and read at my controller page using JavaScript ajax call . 
the alert at jsp page seems to be shoeing that file object is read properly , however nothing is received at controller and ajax giver error response instead of success one .

Following are code snippets im using

jsp file

```
<table>
<tr>
   <td>Profile Picture</td>
   <td><input type="file" id="profilePic"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2"><button id="updatePic" onclick="pic();">submit pic</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

javascript

```
function pic() {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("profilePic", $('#profilePic').get(0).files[0]);
          $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"/sdnext/updateprofile.html",
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            data:{profilePic:formData},
            success:function(data){
                alert("Profile Picture has been updated successfully");
            },
            error:function(data){
                alert("Profile Picture has not been updated successfully");
            }
        });  
}
```

controller

```
   @RequestMapping(value="/updateprofile",method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public @ResponseBody String updateProfile(@RequestParam("profilePic") InputStream profilePic){

     try {
                int i=0;
                ArrayList<Byte> listOfBytes=new ArrayList<Byte>();
                InputStream input=profilePic.getInputStream();
                do{
                    i=input.read();
                    if(i!=-1)
                    {
                        listOfBytes.add((byte) i);
                    }
                }while(i!=-1);
                System.out.println(listOfBytes.size());
                byte []picBytes=new byte[listOfBytes.size()];
                for (int j = 0; j < listOfBytes.size(); j++) {
                    picBytes[j]=listOfBytes.get(j);
                }

        } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
         }

    }
```

Any sample FileIO operation on spring MVC using ajax will be greatly helpful . Any help will be  appreciated .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

check [this](http://hmkcode.com/spring-mvc-upload-file-ajax-jquery-formdata/) answer. It has in detail how to do it.

Comment: As i mentioned in the problem statement , I dont want a solution containing form submit such as <form:form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  
   modelAttribute="uploadedFile" action="fileUpload.htm"> . I hoped for a solution that has ajax component so that page doesn't have to reload on doing so .